# SSDT Import Exception

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2015, sql-server-data-tools

Using VS 2015 and Sql Data Tools, we are trying to import the DB and every time VS is crashing with this error in Event View

> Application: devenv.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
>   process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException    at
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32,
>   IntPtr)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(Int32, Int32[])
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Design.Common.RdtManager.GetDirtyFiles(System.Predicate'1)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Design.Common.RdtManager.SaveDirtyFiles(System.Predicate'1)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Project.DatabaseProjectNode.SaveAllModelFiles()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Project.Features.DataSchemaModelFeature.ExecuteReplacementPlan(ReplacementPlan)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Project.Features.DataSchemaModelFeature.AddScriptsToProject(System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary'2>,
>   System.Nullable'1, System.Nullable'1,
>   System.Nullable'1, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean,
>   Boolean, System.Func'4)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Tools.Package.Project.ImportDatabaseAddScriptJob.Run()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.Common.Threading2.JobManager+JobBase.b__22_0(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)    at
>   Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.Common.Threading2.JobManager+JobBase.Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.Common.Threading2.JobManager.IManageableJob.RunImpl(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(System.Object)
>   at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
>   System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
>   System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()    at
>   System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()

Comment: maybe this can help: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3025135

Comment: The most recent version of VS is VS 2015 Update 3. The most recent version of SSDT is 16.5. Ensure you have the latest version of both.

Comment: I am having Vs2015 Update 3 and running .Net 4.6.2. How do I check the SSDT version.

Comment: I was able to find the version and its 14.0.610210. So I was trying to download the latest from this url https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx. In this it says version 16, but clicking on the link to download https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/mt186501.aspx, it says in the top version Version: 14.0.61021.0. So which is the latest version ?

Comment: They're the same thing. 14.0.61021.0 is the build number, 16.5 the public name. And yes, this is confusing. (DacFx version 16.5 has build number 13.0.3485.1.) So updating won't solve your problem, but now at least you know it's not a solved bug in an old version.

Comment: Does this happen when importing any database? Can you import from a local database? Another on that server?  Wondering if there's something particular about that database or that server that's giving you fits.

Comment: We tried the same DB in two different machine, both had the same problem. Will try now with a different DB now.

Comment: So far I was trying to add to my existing solution. So I tried creating a separate project and add the same DB which had the problem. This time it worked. So at this point looks like something in my solution is causing the problem but I am not able to identify.